# Without implementing the Comparable interface, how does the object of an ArrayList use Collection.sort() without an error?

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, comparator, comparable

Here **ArrayList** & its parent **class & interface** never implemented **Comparable**, Still the ***Collections.sort(al)*** compiled without an error ?

```
public class Collections_Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList al= new ArrayList();
        al.add("ram");
        al.add("shaym");

        Collections.sort(al);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not `ArrayList` that needs to be `Comparable`, it's `String` - and it is.

Comment: This code would be compiled with a raw types warning. Use `ArrayList<String> al= new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: `public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(List<T> list)` so `T` needs to extend `Comparable`, in your case `T` is `String`

Comment: Also: dont use raw types: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it

Answer (score 1):

Look at signature of sort#method

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(List<T> list) {
    list.sort(null);
}
```

This means that not list should implement Comparable to be able to sorted, but type of list elements.

In your case String implements Comparable, so code compile and run without exeptions

Comment: OP's is able to compile not because `String` implements `Comparable`, but because OP is using raw types.

Comment: Sure. Exception will be thrown only when sort will be invoked and under the hood elements will be cast to Comparable

Answer (score 0):

First, `ArrayList` needs not be `Comparable`. The things inside the array list need to be `Comparable`. This is the signature of `sort`:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(List<T> list) {
```

`T` is constrained, not the `List`.

However, using raw types changes everything.

Because you wrote `ArrayList` instead of `ArrayList<String>`, you are using the raw type of `ArrayList`. This basically erases all generic type parameters and makes `sort` not check for any constraints. It is as if the signature became:

```
public static void sort(List list) {
```

That's why you were able to call it. Had you put non-`Comparable` things into the array list, it would have crashed at runtime:

```
ArrayList al= new ArrayList();
al.add(new Object());
al.add(new Object());

Collections.sort(al); // ClassCastException
```

Answer (score 0):

By passing a "comparator" to the sort() method.The comparator allows for custom sorting even if the objects do not follow a natural order.

for example ;

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class Example {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("banana");
    list.add("apple");
    list.add("orange");

    // Custom comparator to sort strings based on length
    Comparator<String> lengthComparator = new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
            return Integer.compare(s1.length(), s2.length());
        }
    };

    // Sorting the list using the custom comparator
    Collections.sort(list, lengthComparator);

    // Print the sorted list
    System.out.println(list);
}
```

}

Once you invoke the list.sort(comparator c),the comparator's compare () method is used and there is NO NEED to implement the comparable interface.  "Head First Java Book.chapter 11,page 332, explains it really well.